# Creating links that update iframe using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, hyperlink

I have created a simple template here:
http://jsfiddle.net/sfntz/

How is it possible to make the links open pages within the iframe without reloading the main page? I would presume that such thing is possible with javascript ajax (something that I have no coding experience with as of yet).

The code I have currently is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    #left-container {
        width: 150px;
        float: left;
    }
    #right-container {
        width: 450px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="left-container">
        <a href="">Link to iFrame 1</a><br/>
        <a href="">Link to iFrame 2</a><br/>
        <a href="">Link to iFrame 3</a><br/>
        <a href="">Link to iFrame 4</a><br/>
        <a href="">Link to iFrame 5</a><br/>
    </div>

    <div id="right-container">
        <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="350px" width="350px">
        </iframe>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use $('#right-container').load('url_of_page_to_load') on click of link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is far more simple than you think:
Just name the iframe and set the target attribute on the link:

```
<iframe src="one.html" name="frame" id="frame"></iframe>
<a href="two.html" target="frame">Next Page</a>
```

With using jQuery, you could try:

```
<iframe src="one.html" name="frame" id="frame"></iframe>
<a href="javascript:$('#frame').load('two.html');">Next Page</a>
```

Comment: That does work indeed. Is there anyway to stop external websites from breaking out of iframe?

Comment: I am not sure, because browsers are very restrictive towards that. But I would say no.

Comment: Also, if you read the comment that was given above, it states that I could use a different technique to accomplish the same thing, what is the difference between these? Do you know?

Comment: Well, this trys to replace the content of the iframe through ajax, while my method is plain html, but with both methods you will have problems with external websites. You could try to search after withCredentials, but I have never used that, so I cant help you there...

Comment: Thank you for the information, can you please update your answer with that other method that was on the comment and I will accept this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try it like that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#left-container a').click(function(_e){
       _e.preventDefault();
       $('#iframe_id').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    }); 
});
</script>
```

just replace the SRC of the iFrame and browser should automatically start loading new source.
Final source with updating your fiddler: [Updated Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/sfntz/2/)

Comment: Does this method function any different to the other two ones posted already? I am just curious...

Comment: yes, this one just changes the frame source w/o reloading the page.
prevent following to link's location and puts the link location as iframe source, so forcing browser to load an iframe content such as it is loads with ajax.

Comment: Interesting! Can you please edit your answer and adjust it with the code that I posted above so that I can see it function with my own code? I will up this regardless.

Comment: Done. Check the fiddler link.